# form serialize illegeal string offset '' on ajax post mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to insert data by form serialize method. This is my ajax.

```
$('#AddInventory').on('click', function () {
    var data = $("#validated_form").serialize();
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            'AddInventory': data
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "Product_DB.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

On alert i got the sending data like [image: this].

This is my DB file, I made changes as per suggestion

```
if (isset($_POST["AddInventory"])) {

    $AddInventory = $_POST["AddInventory"];

    $sql = "insert into `tblinventory` ( Bill_No, SKU_No, Purchase_Price, Discount_Price, Discount, Qty, , Deal, Created_Date, Modified_Date, IsDeleted)values ('" . $AddInventory["Bill_No"] . "','1','" . $AddInventory["Purchase_Price"] . "' ,'" . $AddInventory["Discount_Price"] . "','" . $AddInventory["Discount"] . "','" . $AddInventory["Qty"] . "',,'" . $AddInventory["Deal"] . "',now() ,now() ,'0' )";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    exit();
}
```

**Edit**

Now I am getting

> illegal string offset 'Bill_No'

error ;

I am getting no response in output, in console also there is no script error shown

I have tried to search and implemented the code which I find relevant,
still, the issue persists, any help would be appreciable

**Edit 2**

I tested `var_dump`, I got the response like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the whole `data` in `AddInventory` as URL encoded format, using `parse_str()` you can get it as an array. so in PHP aceess it like this

```
  if(isset($_POST["AddInventory"])){

   parse_str(urldecode($_POST["AddInventory"]),$AddInventory);


      $sql = "insert into `tblinventory` ( Bill_No)values ('".$AddInventory["Bill_No"]."' )";

        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
           echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
     }
```

Important:  Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection , prepare your statements(use PDO)

Comment: remove dataType:'JSON' from your request

Comment: ok , i m getting ajax response , Now it is saying illegal string offset 'Bil_No'

Comment: var_dump($_POST); and paste here

Comment: @FarsheelRahman `dataType` is for the response type that you receive after the ajax call not for the variables your are posting.

Comment: His response is not JSON

Comment: @FarsheelRahman i have pasted screenshot of var_dump , kindly check

Comment: Now it is showing unserialize : error 0 out of 78 bytes

Comment: oh my bad, again updated my answer hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` array does not contain `Bill_no`, instead, it contains url encoded param array.
Use `urldecode($_POST)` function to decode the params to an array, and then take the `Bill_no` from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send data the following way

```
$('#AddInventory').on('click', function () {
    var data = $("#validated_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        data: data + '&AddInventory=1',
        type: "POST",
        url: "Product_DB.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: tx , i got data inserted in db , but not able to get response . How i can i modify to do that ?

Comment: if you need json response you need to use json_encode in your php file to read response in json with ajax, otherwise remove dataType json from the request

Comment: i am not doing with json , can the response be possible without that

Comment: what does network tab show? against the ajax request